# Meteor and jquery - select div by id to toggle class

Tags: jquery, meteor

I'm trying to use jQuery to toggle the class of a div in order to highlight it as being "selected".  These divs are rendered through a loop in the code below:

```
<template name="Watchlist">
<div class="wrapper">
    {{#each watchlist}}
        {{> WatchlistCompany}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

```
<template name="WatchlistCompany">
<div class="wrapper watchlist-company-item" id="{{_id}}">
    <div class="company-text">
        <div id="company-name">
            {{companyName}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the Elements tab, I can see the id's are assigned above using the id of the document that also hold the other fields.  Using the following, I can change the color of the div that has this specific id, but not the others.

```
Template.Watchlist.events({
'click .watchlist-company-item': function(e) {
    $('#8NAQWByZbHFwdFPJg').toggleClass('watchlist-selected');
}
});

.watchlist-selected {
  background-color: darkorange;
}
```

However, these divs are rendered dynamically so this doesn't help.  I'm trying to replicate the code above but first finding the id of the clicked div but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

First I tried assigning the id to a variable.  This doesn't work (nothing happens), even though it's almost exactly like above.

```
Template.Watchlist.events({
'click .watchlist-company-item': function(e) {
    var selectedId = "8NAQWByZbHFwdFPJg";
    $('#selectedId').toggleClass('watchlist-selected');
}
});
```

Next, I tried finding the id from the clicked div, but this doesn't work either (nothing happens.

```
Template.Watchlist.events({
'click .watchlist-company-item': function(e) {
    var selectedId = event.currentTarget.id;
    $('#selectedId').toggleClass('watchlist-selected');
}
});
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the event.currentTarget.id, because if I simply change '#selectedId' to 'div' above, the color of the entire page changes.  So everything short of finding the id is correct.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery with meteor like that is kind of an antipattern. It would do better to set which item is selected in a Session (if vanilla Meteor) or better yet, in a [ReactiveDict](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict).

This way you can do something like:

```
Template.Watchlist.onCreated(function() {
  this.state = new ReactiveDict;
  this.state.set('isSelectedId', null);
});

Template.Watchlist.helpers({
  'isSelected': function() {
    return this._id === Template.instance().state.get('isSelectedId') ? 'is-selected' : '';
  }
});
```

Then on your click event you'd do:

```
Template.Watchlist.events({
  'click .watchlist-company-item': function(e) {
    Template.instance().set('isSelectedId', this._id);
  }
});
```

This is the Meteor approach. Try to avoid jQuery. Use state and reactivity and embrace it!

Learn more here: http://themeteorchef.com/snippets/reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables/

Comment: Thanks.  I'd prefer to do it the Meteor way, but what I don't like about Session or ReactiveDict here is that it will reset on browser refresh.  From a user experience, I would worry about frustration in losing selections.  Am I interpreting this incorrectly?

Comment: @Bren you have that same issue with your code, in fact if you use Meteor `Session` it'll sustain through a hot-code-reload which is otherwise impossible. The only way you can persist through a refresh is through localstorage or db storage. The idea is you want to manipulate the state not the dom.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, for some reason I thought the class would remain on refresh.  Will think more through my use case and take a look at your suggestion, I appreciate the detailed code sample.

Answer (score 3):

```
Template.Watchlist.events({
'click .watchlist-company-item': function(e) {
    $('#'+this._id).toggleClass('watchlist-selected');
}
});
```

That is jQuery selector problem.

Comment: Works great, thank you!  Had never seen that syntax anywhere.